# trying to make the border of the buttons curve fill to the container

Tags: css, flexbox

i am in the process of creating a calculator and want to work on the css first before i move on to javascript. so far i
have encountered a few issues.

1. the window background seems to be much larger than intended
2. the container body that holds the buttons has a edge on the right side which i wish to remove
3. i need the bottom buttons to have a slight curve

Also, if you wish to share anymore additional ideas on how to make it look better i would appreciate it.

```
<body>

<div class="calculator-grid"> 
    <div class="output">
        <div class="display"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="button-container">
        <button class="span-1"> AC </button>
        <button class="span-2"> DEL</button>
        <button class="span-2"> % </button>
        <button class="span-3"> ÷ </button>
        <button> 8 </button>
        <button > 4 </button>
        <button> 9 </button>
        <button class="span-3"> x </button>
        <button >  1 </button>
        <button> 6 </button>
        <button> 5 </button>
        <button class="span-3"> - </button>
        <button> 2 </button>
        <button> 3 </button>
        <button > 7</button>
        <button class="span-3"> + </button>
        <button class="span-4"> 0 </button>
        <button> . </button>
        <button class="span-3"> = </button>
    </div>
 
</div>
```

```
*{
background-color: rgb(182, 208, 228);

}

.calculator-grid{
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
height: 1000px;
width: 1000px;
}

.output {
   height: 100px;
   width: 300px;
   background-color: rgb(36, 38, 52);
   border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
   border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
}.  

  .button-container {
    width: 300px;
    height: 360px;
    background-color:  rgb(53, 57, 88);
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 2px;


}

button {
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
   background-color: rgb(53, 57, 88);
   color: whitesmoke;
   font-size: larger;
}

button.span-1 {
    color: rgb(182, 120, 239);
}

button.span-2 {
    color: rgb(182, 120, 239); 
}

button.span-3 {
   background-color: rgb(182, 120, 239); 
}


button.span-4 {
   width: 140px
}
```

Comment: Could you reproduce your code into a snippet?

Comment: You're using flexbox for a grid system, relaying on `flex-wrap` could prove to be a headache if you don't handle it properly. if you insist on using `flexbox` *(nothing wrong with that)* and don't want surprises, maybe nest row containers for each one. Also you need to figure who is going to enforce the width/height of the calculator, is it a fixed width on the parent and the buttons fit in it, or should the buttons have a min width/height and the parent shrink/grow to fit them?